# Downloading CSV sent from server using react

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, csv, react-native

I'm trying to download a CSV which is returned once I have called an endpoint. It is a CSVActionResult that is returned back and logging the response shows that it is a readable stream. Is there any way I could trigger a download of this file?

I have looked into csv-react but have not had any luck with it. Maybe it's me not using it correctly?

```
*API Call*
.then((response) =>
   <CSVDownload data={response} target="_blank"/>
});
```

Does the response need to be formatted by chance? I did look into a post which said format it to `.json()` but that doesn't seem like the right thing to do in my case.

Response:

[image: My response:]

Comment: Have you tried response.formData()?

Comment: @AliAnkarali I have indeed, seemed to error out with " Uncaught (in promise)TypeError: Failed to fetch"

Comment: Have you tried `response.text()`? There are many more methods for parsing the response object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

Comment: @Stretch0 I have. With `.text()` I can see a better response i.e I can see  fields that should be in the CSV. The issue comes to when downloading using `.text()`. It doesn't throw an error in the console but the request completes successfully but no download is trigger. Could this be an issue with react-csv itself?

Comment: Can we see the markup of your `CSVDownload` component?